# Exclude the last-but-one field

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut, tr

How to exclude or remove the word before the last word in line:

Example:

```
var=1
echo "list $var M"
```

Expected:

```
list 1M
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. It is currently not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your problem is, but this:

```
var=1
echo "list $var M"
```

gives

```
list 1 M
```

To get `list 1M`, use this:

```
var=1
echo "list ${var}M"
list 1M
```

Using `{...}` makes sure the `M` is not part of the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question and expected answer is not matching, I am posting 2 answers.

> 1) To get output as indicated in question, 2) To remove 2nd last word

**1.** `sed 's/ \(\w*$\)/\1/'`

Check for last word (`\w*$`) with the preceding space. Replace the same, but without the space.

**Output:**

```
$ echo "list $var M" | sed 's/ \(\w*$\)/\1/'
list 1M
```

**2.** `sed 's/\w* \(\w*$\)/\1/'`

check for the last 2 words, replace with only the last word.

**Output:**

```
$ echo "list $var M" | sed 's/\w* \(\w*$\)/\1/'
list M
```